# auto space between horizontal divs in CSS

Tags: css, html

I've searched a lot but I was not lucky to find a solution to what I am after!

Here is the issue: I've created a master div (width 100%) and within it there are several inner divs.  You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/EAkLb/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="section_zone">
    <div class="box_frame" id="_15">inner box 1</div>
    <div class="box_frame" id="_15">inner box 2</div>
    <div class="box_frame" id="_15">inner box 3</div>
    <div class="box_frame" id="_15">inner box 4</div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to auto the space-width between the inner divs.

the first-child is aligned to left, and the last-child is aligned to the right, but as you can see, the space between the other divs is not the same.

I hope the following demonstration image be helpful to explain what I am after exactly:

[image: demonstration image]

Please Note: in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EAkLb/1/), I've added 4 inner divs but, the solution I'm after should work no mater how many divs I have (e.g. 2, 3, 4, 5, ...etc) divs.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here is JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sM644/)

Assume that you have 100% and you have 4 pieces. 4 pieces means you have 3 margin-left block so, when you make your div 22*4=88 then 100-88=12 then 12/3=4 then your margin-left must be:4

```
div.box_frame{
    float: left;
    background-color: #eee; /* standard background color */
    border: 1px solid #898989; 
    border-radius: 11px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-left:4%;
    text-align: center;
    /* change border to be inside the box */
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
div.box_frame:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;
}
div.box_frame#_15{ /* width 15% */
    width: 22%;
}
```

So if you use less variables then you can use this solution without depending on number of div blocks

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, you cannot use the same `ID` more than once per `HTML` page.

Secondly, you are on the right track. Just use a `margin-right` on *every* element, then proceed to add a `psuedo-class` of `last-child` and set `margin` to `0`.

#### http://jsfiddle.net/EAkLb/1/

To make it work that way for `any amount of divs`, it would be best practice to still establish a `percentage` that makes sense. (ie 25% for 4, 33% for 3, 16.6% for 6, etc)

---

**EDIT:**

This here would be a much better way to do it (try resizing the window):

#### http://jsfiddle.net/EAkLb/5/

Comment: Also, just wanted to mention you'd be MUCH better off using `ul` and `li`... just sayin` ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for `id` tip. I am new to css and I don't know what you mean by `psuedo-class`; would you please update the fiddle with it?

Comment: It's in there :-) A `psuedo-class` is a way that you can target the **last** element in the object. So `box_frame:last-child {` will only target the last `box_frame` it finds.

Comment: thanks, I will try it. BTW, in the fiddle, there is no space between the `li`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this effect by putting `display:inline-block` on all child elements, and then apply `text-align-last:justify` to the parent container to enable evenly spaced inline child elements.

[See working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/GPCbn/1/).

There are a few caveats however - [while Firefox has supported this since v12, and IE even since 5.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last), there is officially no support in Webkit. It **is** however working fine in Chrome 32-beta with certain flags enabled, while it's not working in Chrome 31-stable or current iOS Safari builds for example.

Secondly, IE seems to only respect `text-align-last` when there is also a `text-align` declaration of the same type (which doesn't conform to standards).

I am not aware of any way to achieve this effect cleanly in another way in older Webkit browsers, but you could solve this by a margin-based fallback for example, or have a JS-based calculation at runtime.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me (chrome v32.0.1700.72 m): http://i.imgur.com/Xzl8Yk1.png

Comment: Weird, I'm running the same version and it is - could be that I have some 'experimental features' flag enabled though. Doesn't seem like it's going to be in Webkit anywhere soon.

Comment: Not backward compatible.

Comment: Seriously? Perhaps that's why I devoted an entire paragraph to explaining that it doesn't work in currently active Webkit browsers?